# Overview for properties of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

I was wondering if there exists a nice overview for properties of modules like being cyclic, simple, semisimple, indecomposable, free, noetherian, artinian and having finite length. I'm thinking about some kind of diagram or table that shows which property implies which under certain conditions or provides counterexamples. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The Database of Ring Theory has a section for modules now too.  Unfortunately, I have not yet included dot graphs for the relationships between properties, but I generated one just for you here.

Don't take the chart as anything close to comprehensive: it's just starting out.  There aren't any comprehensive resources, really.

As for examples and counterexamples, you can [browse examples here](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/modules/) and [do searches here](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/modules/search) and so on.

There are more theorems used than is evident from this simple graph, but they are currently only accessible [through the github repo](https://github.com/rschwiebert/dart_data/tree/master/db/moduleapp/logic).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I'm not very advanced in the theory of modules anyway and have no idea about 60% of the properties you mentioned, so it's not a problem for me if the graph is not complete yet.

Comment: @algebrah Sure, and if you find anything that might be useful to include let me know here or there or in github.  I haven't had much opportunity to expand the module section  recently.